# Is it possbile to muxing a HEVC Annex B raw video file into a container(mp4,mkv..etc) without changing its start code with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, containers, encode, hevc

I have a code that extracting raw HEVC from a hevc/mp4 file

```
ffmpeg -i video3.mp4 -c:v copy -bsf hevc_mp4toannexb output.hevc
```

and I've read this topic: 
[How to properly wrap H264 into FLV with FFMPEG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484607/how-to-properly-wrap-h264-into-flv-with-ffmpeg) 
It's about a method that can wrap a raw H264 video in to flv with ffmpeg. Then i researched google for a while but i can't figure a way wrap HEVC Annex B raw video file into a mp4 container without changing its start code( every NALU starts with a start code 0x000001 or 0x00000001 ), so is it possible with ffmpeg?

Comment: MP4 files require NALUs begins with their size, and does not use start codes.

Comment: Is exist a container use start codes and can contain audio steam?

Comment: Transport stream

Comment: I can't copy directly into .ts container.It required transcoding

Comment: [mpegts @ 000002270ba2e100] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly. 
[mpegts @ 000002270ba2e100] first pts value must be set
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: If you have more questions, please open a new post to ask it so others may find it later.